# Google play console Vital reports and firebase crashlytics reports connection

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-play-console, android-vitals

I published a version of an app last month, calling the version 1.0.000. After that, I have been publishing multiple other versions of the app after version 1.0.000.

I can see that the Firebase crash-free percentage is going down significantly, and I couldn't figure out the major contributor from the Crashlytics.

This morning, I visited the Google Play Console to check the Android vitals and found that there is one feature which is showing a crash on the Play Console and is among the top contributors to the crash rate.

After that, I tried to check the same logs from the play console, on the Firebase Crashlytics. But no success. I couldn't find the same logs.

Now my question is, is there any connection between numbers showing in Firebase Crashlytics and Google Play Console crash rate?